# Менеджмент front-end зависимостей на Ruby

Tags: ruby, gems, зависимости

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу с выводом в браузер. Для нее (помимо rubygems) нужно несколько зависимостей: CSS, шрифты, JavaScript библиотека. Надо организовать управление зависимостей, в первую очередь хотя бы скачивание по команде.
Варианты, которые я придумал:

- Это может организовать Bower, но, так как программа распространяемая, не хотелось бы заставлять пользователей устанавливать помимо Ruby еще и Node.js только чтобы загрузить зависимости.
- Можно распространять прямо с программой, но программа будет в Open Source на GitHub, а засовывать чужие проекты в свой репозиторий, пусть даже и с дисклеймером, как-то неудобно. Плюс самому придется следить за версиями каждой библиотеки и делать отдельный commit под каждую версию каждой зависимости.
- Можно сделать это через Rake + GitHub + Net::HTTP + File.write, но это как-то ненадежно и займет дополнительную кучу кода, который надо поддерживать
- Gem обертки, как известно, почти никогда никем не обновляются

Есть еще пара идей, но они на данный момент не кажутся реализуемыми:

- Bower, увы, не предоставляет публичного Web API
- CDN не вариант, так как программа, опять же, распространяемая и должна работать и без подключения к интернету
- Gem под данную задачу не нашел (подробнее ниже)

Пробовал также искать gem, но результаты плачевны:

- giternal и rip позволяли загружать зависимости c git репозиториев, но они давно никем не поддерживаются и не проходят большинство тестов
- rails-assets и torba только для sprockets, а мне не хочется переписывать весь проект под гем, который, слишком мягко говоря, мне совершенно не нравится.

Comment: "rails-assets и torba только для sprockets" - то есть в своем проекте вы используете систему сборки, отличную от sprockets? Если так, то какую? И есть ли для этой системы сборки стабильные и подходящие под нее системы управления зависимостями?

Comment: Виталий, у меня нет системы сборки: проект на Sinatra и файлы отдаются клиенту в том же виде, который лежит в файловой системе. Поэтому я не могу использовать формат расположения sprockets: насколько я понимаю из того, что мне установил torba, он подразумевает кучу случайных символов после имени зависимости в именах директорий.

Comment: Sprockets делает так, да. И это хорошо - это гарантирует, что при обновлении стилей и скриптов, у пользователей будут скачиваться обновленные версии файлов. Без этих случайных символов (называется это - fingerprint и assets digest) есть высокий риск, что даже после обновления сайта, у пользователей будут грузиться старые закешированные браузером стили и скрипты.

Comment: В любом случае, хороший это метод или плохой, мне необходимо получить стили и скрипты без него: я же буду стили вручную подключать, а с fingerprint при первом же обновлении все слетит.

Comment: *так как программа распространяемая* -- а каким образом её планируется распространять?

Comment: В нескольких видах: 1) через `git clone` для разработчиков; 2) через gem для тех, у кого есть установленный ruby. Для остальных 3) в самодостаточных пакетах, содержащих ruby и все зависимости. Соответственно, в 1 варианте все зависимости загружаются по команде `rake`, во 2 front-end уже включен в gem, а gemы установятся сами, в 3 и gem и front-end зависимости распространяются вместе с программой. Проблема, соответственно, в загрузке front-end в первом варианте.

Comment: @Juickl учитывая общую склонность господ-фронтендщиков налаживать процессы разработки ассетов через NodeJS, я бы просто поставил его в требования. Ведь, как вы сами заметили, это потребуется только тем, кто хочет **самый свежак**, а не упакованный релиз и, возможно, захочет ассеты доработать.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо. Действительно, как-то сам не додумался. Но все же если кто знает что-нибудь на Ruby, ответы все ещё принимаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В фронтэнде Node.js крепко укоренился для сборки и преобразования всего и вся. Поэтому требовать установленный Node.js для модификации ассетов это дело нынче вполне обычное. Посему, для полной среды разработки под ваш проект **Node.js всё равно понадобится**. Бежать от него бесполезно — догонит.

Для вас в основном стоит задача *"не заставлять конечных пользователей ставить Node.js, т. к. во время выполнения он уже не нужен"*. Но конечные пользователи скорее возьмут готовую сборку, чем будут делать её сами, и если в готовых сборках ассеты уже собраны, то и Node.js им не понадобится. Следовательно, задача уже решена.

`git clone` не предназначен для распространения сборок. Вот совсем.

---

Если вас нервирует необходимость заставлять даже ради разработки исключительно серверной части ставить зависимости ассетов, то можно сделать ход конём и **вынести их в отдельный гем**. А при генерации конфигов для вебсервера (или настройке встроенного) можно узнать, куда гем с ассетами установлен (на примере `activesupport`):

```
# они работают немножко по-разному, вас интересует скорее первое
Bundler.rubygems.find_name('activesupport').first.full_gem_path
Gem::Specification.find_by_name('activesupport').gem_dir
```

Это может иметь смысл где ассеты и серверная часть очень слабо связаны друг с дружкой, если ассеты образуют что-то SPA-подобное, например.

И, соответственно, работает прежнее решение: вы пакуете релизы ассетов заранее, а кому надо заняться разработкой, по желанию может поставить уже упакованные.